# How to apply a CSS rule selectively?

Tags: css

I have the following in my css file:

```
md-menu-content.md-menu-bar-menu.md-dense .md-menu > .md-button:after{
    display:none;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<md-menu-content class="ZZZ">
    Hello
</md-menu-content>
```

I have some Javascript (material design) that adds lots of stuff to the `<md-menu-content>` elements.

I would like to apply the above CSS to certain `<md-menu-content>` elements (only if they have the ZZZ class) and leave all others behaving as normal. I'm very stuck. Is this possible in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

To apply the css that you want to all items of the `ZZZ` class, you should use code like this:

```
.ZZZ {
    //your code here
}
```

The `.` before the `ZZZ` signifies that it applies to items with the class `ZZZ`. This can be done with any class, as all you have to do is put a `.` (period) before the class name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over thinking this, just use the **css** styling like you would any other time, and it works just fine. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pyexm7us/3/

**HTML**

```
<md-menu-content class="ZZZ">
    Hello
</md-menu-content>
<md-menu-content>
    World
</md-menu-content>
```

**CSS**

```
md-menu-content{background-color: red; color: white;}
.ZZZ{background-color: blue; color: white;}
```

Comment: I was trying to apply the style `display: none;` to items matching `md-menu-content.md-menu-bar-menu.md-dense .md-menu > .md-button:after` and `ZZZ` How to do this?

Comment: Are they all separate elements or are they concatenated? Could you show me a snippet of the HTML? I know how to do it but it depends on how your html is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible with CSS

To apply styling to elements with the same `class` simply use the prefix `.`

```
.ZZZ {
    //styling for elements with class ZZZ
}
```

If you want to work with `id`'s then use the prefix `#`

```
#ZZZ {
    //styling for elements with the ID ZZZ
}
```

Comment: Eh, I want to apply the style `display: none;` to items matching `md-menu-content.md-menu-bar-menu.md-dense .md-menu > .md-button:after` AND `ZZZ` How to do this?

Comment: `md-menu-content.ZZZ` this will apply a styling to any `md-menu-content` with the `ZZZ` class. If you do `md-menu-content .ZZZ` (with a space) that means any element with the class `ZZZ` that is a child of `md-menu-content`